# Can I setup a web hook for a Method in Azure Api Management?

Tags: webhooks, azure-api-management

So, I have an API in Azure-API-Management, which is attached to a function. I want to expose one the method in API as Web-hook for another application CRM. It will be an inbound web-hook.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A webhook endpoint is like any other HTTP endpoint that usually expects a POST request from an external system. So, yes.

Depending on the CRM Application, you could leverage APIMs built-in security features to authenticate the webhook call without having to validate credentials in your function as a bonus for using APIM.