# Github webhook to auto deploy to Azure API Management Services

Tags: azure, github, cicd

I have an api hosted in Azure API Management Services. It was deployed through the Publish feature in Visual Studio.

Now I've been asked to set up Github webhook integration so that my endpoint auto deploys to Azure after each commit.

From my understanding of webhooks, they are essentially POST calls that are triggered after an event.

My question is where to create the webhook url and how to have it deploy latest github code to Azure API management services?

Comment: Have you gone through [this blog post](https://blog.memoryleek.co.uk/2021/09/14/deploying-api-management-apis-using-github-actions.html) on `Deploying api management api using git hub actions`. Does this helpful ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I setup a web hook for a Method in Azure Api Management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63584859/can-i-setup-a-web-hook-for-a-method-in-azure-api-management)

Comment: [How to save and configure your API Management service configuration using Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git) and [Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops)